# Running `npm install` changes installed multer version

Tags: npm, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

I'm currently working on a node project that uses multer and multer-gridfs-storage.

I'm trying to use multer version 1.4.4-lts.1. When I install multer and specify this version on its own, node installs it as expected. However, when I install all the dependencies of the project (via a simple `npm install`), the version of multer changes to 1.4.4.

This wouldn't be a huge deal, except 1.4.4 has a high-severity CVE, and I'd really like to avoid that by using 1.4.4-lts.1.

### Steps to reproduce

I've run `npm install multer@1.4.4-lts.1`, and I have ensured that my `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files show multer version 1.4.4-lts.1.

However, when I then run `npm install` (either in the same environment or from within a Docker container), it changes the multer version to 1.4.4. Additionally, when I then run `npm install multer@1.4.4-lts.1` again, npm alerts me of a conflicting peer dependency with multer-gridfs-storage:
[A screenshot of a bash terminal showing what happens when installing multer 1.4.4-lts.1 after previously installing multer 1.4.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvFOH.png).

Is there any way I can ensure that node installs multer@1.4.4-lts.1, while still satisfying multer-gridfs-storage's dependency?